# Understanding How this Phantastron Circuit Works

Tags: circuit-analysis, vacuum-tube

I'm having a hard time gaining an intuitive understanding of, and modeling with an equation, this particular circuit linked below. It's called a "Phantastron", and it was used in old radar timing technology and in some parts of Europe, in TV sweep circuits. I am confused about two things. One, why is the input pulse going into the suppressor grid? Based on my limited understanding of pentodes shouldn't that grid just go to ground to repel reflected electrons? Second, I am super confused about what C1 does and how it works. I'm used to capacitors for AC coupling, filtering, and smoothing, but I've never seen a capacitor used like this and I have no idea what it does or what equation describes it. The Output of the circuit is pin 8 of the pentode, and it's supposed to produce a saw-tooth waveform.

[image: Phantastron]

Comment: Is "phantastron" the name of the circuit, or is it a special type of pentode? Generally (though not always) things ending in -tron are types of vacuum tube, not circuits involving them, so maybe this is a weird type of tube.

Comment: Can you describe what it does? It's hard to guess how it works when I've doesn't even know what it's supposed to do

Comment: @Hearth It's a fairly normal [sharp-cutoff pentode](https://www.tubesandmore.com/sites/default/files/associated_files/6sj7.pdf) used for audio (and some radio) amplification. They also made remote-cutoff ones where they screwed around with a helix wind (tapered it, I think) so that the cutoff was weird and gradual -- used more for AGC. So this is a 'normal' tube to my mind.

Comment: please add a link to the source of that schematic diagram to your post ... it is a requirement of this site ... do not use a comment to add the info

Comment: @Hearth Circuit name. One of the unusual cases where they named the entire mode of operation.

Comment: The screen is used as a second grid. You can make a pentode work like a triode by biasing the control grid and screen properly. This triode-like operation is most useful in hard-switching digital circuits. It's slower than normal pentode operation, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems in this circuit the capacitively coupled input signal gives a temporary negative pulse to the suppressor grid which turns the tube off and allows C1 to charge/recharge. This starts the process of generating a ramp voltage. In this form the circuit becomes a one-shot sawtooth generator. C1 itself is the main timing cap that integrates the signal along with the resistors connected to it. All this is per the Phantastron circuit description found in [this document](http://rabjohn.ca/data/documents/Phantastron.pdf).  (See Figure 2 and the paragraph above that.)

As a side note: The circuit is claimed to have been developed by a British engineer named Blumlein in 1942, ([per this article](https://www.radartutorial.eu/17.bauteile/bt52.en.html)). Calling it a Phantastron circuit rather than a Blumlein circuit obviously makes it sound a bit more interesting. Apparently Blumlein was a very notable Engineer back in the day. He is credited for inspiring the invention of stereo, and over 100 patents, (in case anyone was wondering). Also see [more info here](https://www.cnet.com/science/meet-alan-blumlein-the-man-who-invented-stereo/).
.